# Why am I getting "not all Code path Returns a value error" on Func Delegate

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, action, func

I have a method which accepts a Func :

```
private void testFuncCallBack(Func<string> funcDelegate)
        {
           //Some Code
        }
```

Now I want to call and pass a func as a parameter:

```
  testFuncCallBack(() =>{"";});
```

Now I get a error saying not all code path returns a value. But as soon as I remove the curly braces and `;` it works fine.

Why Func does not compile with Curly Braces.

The Same works with Action though:

```
private void testActionCallBack(Action actionDelegate)
        {
            //Some Code
        }
 testActionCallBack(() => { int x = 10; });
```

Comment: The right call is testFuncCallBack(delegate() { return ""; }); As far as I have given a clearly wrong answer showing my lack of understanding of the exact situation, I will not post it as an answer. Just FYI the error in my previous reasoning was thinking that Func<string> funcDelegate indicated a void taking a string as argument, rather than what it really is: a string function taking no arguments. Sorry about the misinformation. Logically, this wasn't an answer coming from my own experience (I rarely use Func<>) but from a badly-perfomed, quick research, apologies.

Comment: @varocarbas, Not a problem , Just Found out when we place something inside curly braces then it becomes a statement rather than an expression. So We can Write it as  testFuncCallBack(() =>""); or  testFuncCallBack(() =>{ return "";});. SO in later case if it's a statement, it is better to return some value.

Comment: Thanks for the proper explanation. Intuitively, I do understand that within curly brackets you have to include all the information which have to be assigned to the given variable (e.g., int x = 10; as an action. Or {1, 2, 3} as the contents of an array of ints). Thus I did understand from the start that associating ""; with a whole delegate didn't sound too right. While performing the pre-research, I did find the link I posted + some times I am a bit impulsive... and here you saw the result :) (I am new on stackoverflow and still learning to stop doing these things).

Answer (score 0):

When we write something inside curly braces then it becomes a statement rather than an expression.

In this case when we are talking about lambda expressions, the expression =>"" will do the return the "". But if We want to make a statement , then the statement has to complete with return;

So We can Write it as `testFuncCallBack(() =>"")`; or `testFuncCallBack(() =>{ return "";});`. SO in later case if it's a statement, it is better to return some value.